# Overriding PHP session id

Tags: php, session

I'm creating my own `SessionHandler` class implementing `SessionHandlerInterface`.

According to [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) I have to implement 5 methods: `close()`, `destroy($session_id)`, `gc($maxlifetime)`, `open($save_path, $session_id)`, `read($session_id)` and `write($session_id, $session_data)`.

The manual even offers a sample implementation and it's quite straight forward. The only problem I have is PHP session ids are always of the form:

> hpuhqm4ppmdfaat5s1qmt5s397

but I'd like to change that for a more standarized [uuidv5](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php#94959).

Since the $session_id is a parameter passed to all the methods, the only way I can think of doing that is by overriding the already generated session id using `session_id($uuidv5)` on the `open($save_path, $session_id)` method implementation, and that doesn't seem right.

Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Btw, if `session_id($uuidv5)` works for you, why do you think it doesn't look right? AFAIK that's the only function that is able to set the session id in userland code. Take care you've got enough entropy on generating the session Id not that you're running into security issues just for your (cosmetic?) reasons. There generally is some chance to degrade session security by changing the session ID scheme.

Comment: because it's not optimal and it feels counterintuitive. Maybe you are right and I shouldn't be modifying the algo in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a cleaner way to do it?

Change the underlying PHP session ID creation function. It uses hashes and by default is configurable (read more at [`session.hash_function` PHP ini directive](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.hash-function) or [`session.save_handler`](http://php.net/session.save-handler)), however if the existing configuration options don't match your *uuidv5* needs, you need to add it to PHP's core code or via a PHP extension.

---

Further information as you moaned in the comment about that it would be "overkill" to write a PHP extension:

The userland PHP session save handler interface does not contain the core session save handlers `s_create_sid` method which is actually what you're looking for. This makes things hard in userland because that functionality is just not intended to be done in userland.

As session ID creation is subject to security and PHP core developers have already learned in the past that it was easy to do mistakes here, they even trust less others esp. those using the language, to easily change sessions ID generation here (my speculation as otherwise the function could have been exported to the userland session save handler).

However you can create UUIDs your own for being used *with* session IDs by then just *hashing* them in the configured manner *as* session IDs.

You could then keep the non-hashed value that is of the UUID form as a session variable.

If you actually need the UUID on the front-end, then I'd tend to say (if even this is possible to say in an SO answer) what you do is fishy and I would double check your motivations. Because technically only *some* ID is necessary, there should be no format requirements so I don't see any reason to not re-use the existing session IDs.

Comment: From what I understand I can only configure the kind of hash used. I cannot set it to the uuidv5 algo I want to use. Extending PHP seems an overkill...

Comment: Well, it's not my fault if someones requirement to must have some XYZ-Super-Cooolie-Found-In-Some-Note-Algorithm results in exorbitant manners. Don't shoot the messenger. See as well: [`session.save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.session.save_handler) (It's also not PHP core developers fault. You might want to outline in your question why you need it, if it's a useful feature, I see no reason to not get it into PHP core)

Comment: @elcodedocle: I added some more background infos why it's not easily possible in userland-code.

Comment: That's very good insight you are providing. You also made me question why I want to do this. I want uuidv5 session ids because I am storing my sessions on the database. I imagine the app as a data cruncher. And I want to have as many data crunchers as I want and I don't want to be caring of what particular data cruncher a client hits on a particular request. But maybe that's not a good idea...